# How to perform automated test in webview

Tags: java, performance, automated-tests, appium-android, software-quality

I have Android native app and I want to test login page witch was developed using webview that’s open central Authenticator. I’m trying to use appium to test but I’ve see that appium cannot test webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium can test Webview. It is just that you have to switch to the right context.

[get-context](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/get-context/) helps in getting current context.

[get-contexts](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/get-contexts/) helps in getting all the contexts available to automate.

[set-context](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/) helps in setting the desired context.